# NHibernate many-to-one and bidirectional access

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-one

What HBM do I have to write for `Blog` and `Post` to have a bidirectional relationship between these tables? 
I tried `many-to-one` from both sides but run into the following problems (most likely because I did it totally wrong):

- Transient persistance errors inserting the object graph in one `Session`.
- Foreign key issues with the `Blog` and `Post` tables referencing each other.

**Note**: My example is contrived, please don't argue the design.

***Design:***

[image: Design]

***Source:***

```
public class Blog
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment LastComment { get; set; }  // last-comment

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Feedback { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; } //commented-on
}
```

**HBM:**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Sample" 
 namespace="Sample">
  <class name="Blog">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <!-- How to map Comment? -->
    <bag name="Posts">
      <key column="BlogId" />
      <one-to-many class="Post" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Post">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <property name="Feedback" />
    <bag name="Comments">
      <key column="PostId" />
      <one-to-many class="Comment" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Comment">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <property name="Comment" />
    <!-- How to map back to Blog? -->
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

***Required DB structure:***

```
+------------------------------+
| Blog                         |
+--------------+---------------+
| Id           | int           |
| Name         | nvarchar(50)  |
| LastCommentId| int (null)    |
+--------------+---------------+

+------------------------------+
| Post                         |
+--------------+---------------+
| Id           | int           |
| BlogId       | int           |
+--------------+---------------+

+------------------------------+
| Comment                      |
+--------------+---------------+
| Id           | int           |
| PostId       | int           |
| BlogId       | int (not-null)|
| Feedback     | nvarchar(200) |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear as to why this is the required structure; if a post belongs to a blog, then why is a comment belonging to a post not enough information to figure out which blog it's on?

Comment: @Paul as I mentioned the example is contrived. My real example is to complicated to try an explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a **Blog** property to **Post** if it needs to be not-null (see the last paragraph in [6.4. One-To-Many Associations](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany))

Here are some mappings that should work:

```
<class name="Blog" dynamic-update="true">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <many-to-one name="LastComment" column="LastCommentId" cascade="all" />
  <bag name="Posts" cascade="all" inverse="true">
    <key column="BlogId" />
    <one-to-many class="Post" />
  </bag>
</class>
<class name="Post">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </id>
  <property name="Content" />
  <many-to-one name="Blog" column="BlogId" />
  <bag name="Comments" inverse="true">
    <key column="PostId" />
    <one-to-many class="Comment" />
  </bag>
</class>
<class name="Comment">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </id>
  <property name="Feedback" />
  <many-to-one name="Blog" column="BlogId" not-null="true" cascade="all" />
</class>
```

Then you'll be able to use code like the following:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var blog = new Blog { Name = "My Blog" };
    var post = new Post { Blog = blog, Content = "My First Post" };
    var comment = new Comment { Blog = blog, Feedback = "Awesome!" };
    blog.LastComment = comment;
    blog.Posts = new List<Post> { post };
    post.Comments = new List<Comment> { comment };
    session.Save(comment);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

This inserts the **Blog**, then the **Post**, then the **Comment**, then it updates the **Blog** to set the **LastCommentId**.

Note that you need to call **Save** on the **Comment**; anything else will fail.

Comment: Hello Diego,  thanks for the trouble you took to answer this question.  It is working perfectly now.  Interestingly enough setting `dynamic-update=true` is required to get this to work for my real-life scenario.  I have some event listeners on the "Blog" table that applies audit field changes to it.  Without that setting it fails.  That was the key to make it work, I don't know how you knew to it add it, just brilliant, thanks!